# Why $\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{n!} = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why  $\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{n!} = 0$? I know it's convergent by ratio test, but why is it equal to zero? Is it equal to some well-known function?

Comment: Note that $\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{n!}=\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}+\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)!}$. Do you see how to conclude?

Comment: Hint: $\frac {n+1}n! =\frac 1 {(n-1)!} + \frac 1 {n!} $.  The series telescopes.

Comment: @Ian Oh I didn't realize that $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n(n+1)\frac{x^n }{n!}$.

$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt = \sum_0^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1} }{n!} = x e^{-x}$,
and so $f(x) = F'(x) = (1-x)e^{-x}$.

Then $f(1) = 0$.